# SQL - How to avoid a repeating row when joining tables via a junction table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, many-to-many

I'm building a Pokemon API, and I'm having trouble with a repeating row when joining via a junction table. It is a SQL Server database. A watered down version of my tables looks like this:

[image: Database Tables]

To recreate my database:

```
CREATE DATABASE PokeApi;
USE PokeApi;

CREATE TABLE Pokemon (
    PokemonId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    PokemonName VARCHAR(55),
    NationalDexNumber INT,
    PokemonHeight INT,
    PokemonWeight DECIMAL(10,2),
    Category VARCHAR(50),
    Gender VARCHAR(15),
    GenderDifference BIT,
    TypeOne VARCHAR(15),
    TypeTwo VARCHAR(15),
);

CREATE TABLE Abilities (
    AbilityId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    AbilityName VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE PokemonAbilitiesMapped (
    PokemonId INT NOT NULL,
    AbilityId INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_PokemonAbilitiesMapped PRIMARY KEY
    (
        PokemonId,
        AbilityId
    ),
    FOREIGN KEY(PokemonId) REFERENCES Pokemon(PokemonId),
    FOREIGN KEY(AbilityId) REFERENCES Abilities(AbilityId)
);

INSERT INTO Pokemon
VALUES
  ('Venusaur', 3, 79, 220.5, 'Seed', 'Male / Female', 1, 'Grass', 'Poison'),
  ('Mega Venusaur', 3, 94, 342.8, 'Seed', 'Male / Female', 0, 'Grass', 'Poison'),
  ('Gigantamax Venusaur', 3, 945, NULL, 'Seed', 'Male / Female', 1, 'Grass', 'Poison');

INSERT INTO Abilities
VALUES
  ('Overgrow'),
  ('Thick Fat'),
  ('Test');

INSERT INTO PokemonAbilitiesMapped
VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (2, 2),
  (3, 1),
  (3, 3);
```

My query:

```
SELECT p.PokemonName, p.NationalDexNumber, p.PokemonHeight, p.PokemonWeight,
p.Category, p.Gender, p.GenderDifference, p.TypeOne, p.TypeTwo,
a.AbilityName
FROM Pokemon p
JOIN PokemonAbilitiesMapped pam
ON p.PokemonId = pam.PokemonId
JOIN Abilities a
ON pam.AbilityId = a.AbilityId
```

Outputs this:

| PokemonName | NationalDexNumber | PokemonHeight | PokemonWeight | Category | Gender | GenderDifference | TypeOne | TypeTwo | AbilityName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Venusaur | 3 | 79 | 220.50 | Seed | Male / Female | True | Grass | Poison | Overgrow |
| Mega Venusaur | 3 | 94 | 342.80 | Seed | Male / Female | False | Grass | Poison | Thick Fat |
| Gigantamax Venusaur | 3 | 945 | *null* | Seed | Male / Female | True | Grass | Poison | Overgrow |
| Gigantamax Venusaur | 3 | 945 | *null* | Seed | Male / Female | True | Grass | Poison | Test |

As you can see, *Gigantamax Venusaur* is listed twice because it has two abilities. I was thinking that I could add another column called "AbilityNameTwo" only if the pokemon queried had a second ability to avoid the row repeating.

What is the best way to avoid repeating data in this scenario? If I should add another column when joining, how would I write that as a query?

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Assuming you need the ability name, you wouldn't normally try and avoid the row appearing twice - its correct as returned. But really it depends on what you are using the data for. Adding a column per ability gets into a tricky situation because then you have a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: You are still not clearly giving desired output in words or data. What is "avoid repeating data"? What is the (1) question? [mre] [ask] PS When this is clear it seems likely to be a faq. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) PS None of those images belong. An ERD is DDL, tables are text. It's good your input tables are code but please format in columns.

Comment: To avoid duplicating the rows, you can add the abilities as comma separated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly normal to have results like that when joining data. If you really want to, you can have "ability two", but what if some pokemon has three, or five? And how do you order them? Here's an example of how you'd do it for two abilities and ordering alphabetically:

```
WITH abilitiesMapped AS
(
    SELECT pam.PokemonId
         , a.AbilityName
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pam.PokemonId 
                                  ORDER BY a.AbilityName) AS abilityNo
      FROM PokemonAbilitiesMapped pam
      JOIN Abilities a
        ON a.AbilityId = pam.AbilityId
)
SELECT p.PokemonName, p.NationalDexNumber, p.PokemonHeight, p.PokemonWeight,
p.Category, p.Gender, p.GenderDifference, p.TypeOne, p.TypeTwo
   , ability1.abilityName AS ability1
   , ability2.abilityName AS ability2
FROM Pokemon p
LEFT OUTER
JOIN abilitiesMapped ability1
  ON ability1.PokemonId = p.PokemonId
 AND ability1.abilityNo = 1
LEFT OUTER
JOIN abilitiesMapped ability2
  ON ability2.PokemonId = p.PokemonId
 AND ability1.abilityNo = 2
```

CTE abilitiesMapped takes your mappings and abilities and generates an abilityNo for each pokemon (`PARTITION BY pam.PokemonId`) where the number is ordered by the ability name (`ORDER BY ...`). Then this CTE is joined twice for abilityNo 1 and 2. `LEFT JOIN` is important because a pokemon does not necessarily need to have two abilities, and you will get a NULL in ability2 in such case (with an `INNER JOIN` you'd only get the ones that have two abilities because abilityNo = 2 needs to exist in order to satisfy the join condition).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post with create, insert statements. It was very helpful.

To avoid duplication of the ability name, You can make the ability names as comma separated list. I am using `STR_AGG` to generate comma separated list. It is available from SQL Server 2017 onwards. For earlier versions, you have to use `FOR XML PATH` to generate comma separated list.

```sql
SELECT p.PokemonName, p.NationalDexNumber, p.PokemonHeight, p.PokemonWeight,
p.Category, p.Gender, p.GenderDifference, p.TypeOne, p.TypeTwo,
STRING_AGG(a.AbilityName,',') AS Abilities
FROM Pokemon p
JOIN PokemonAbilitiesMapped pam
ON p.PokemonId = pam.PokemonId
JOIN Abilities a
ON pam.AbilityId = a.AbilityId
GROUP BY p.PokemonName, p.NationalDexNumber, p.PokemonHeight, p.PokemonWeight,
p.Category, p.Gender, p.GenderDifference, p.TypeOne, p.TypeTwo
```

| PokemonName | NationalDexNumber | PokemonHeight | PokemonWeight | Category | Gender | GenderDifference | TypeOne | TypeTwo | Abilities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gigantamax Venusaur | 3 | 945 | NULL | Seed | Male / Female | 1 | Grass | Poison | Overgrow,Test |
| Mega Venusaur | 3 | 94 | 342.80 | Seed | Male / Female | 0 | Grass | Poison | Thick Fat |
| Venusaur | 3 | 79 | 220.50 | Seed | Male / Female | 1 | Grass | Poison | Overgrow |